# Div moving in cycle rotation using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dhtml

Is it possible to rotate a Div in cyclic rotation using JavaScript. I have four DIVs in an HTML page. I need to rotate those DIVs in a cyclic rotation.

Comment: Please format you question as normal text; it seems that you've formatted it as a code block (which it isn't!).

Answer (score 4):

It's actually not hard:

```
function moveDiv(t,mdiv) {
            t = t + 0.05; // "time"
            var r = 10, //radius of circle
                xcenter = 400, //x location of circles centre on screen
                ycenter = 400, //y location of circles centre on screen
                x = Math.floor(xcenter + (r * Math.cos(t))), //circles parametric function
                y = Math.floor(ycenter + (r * Math.sin(t))); //circles parametric function
            mDiv.style.top = x + "px"; //set divs new coordinates
            mDiv.style.left = y + "px"; //set divs new coordinates

            setTimeout(function() { //make sure the animation keeps going
                moveDiv(t,mdiv);
            }, 100);
}
    myDiv = //get div element
    moveDiv(1,myDiv); //start the animation
```

Haven't tested, but that's about how it should work. Make sure you set css "position" property of those divs to absolute or fixed. Also take a look at [parametric equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation) for circle.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use the [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) JavaScript library to accomplish something like this.

Steve

Comment: that's an awesome library, only downside is that its not cross browser because most browsers held off on the implementation of SVG. All major current browser releases support SVG though.

Comment: You can probably test for SVG support in IE and show them where they need to download the adobe plugin that makes your site work.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the question, but take a look at the 'Cycle' jQuery plugin: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/

Answer (score 0):

this could possibly be done... but not easily, and you wouldn't be able to maintain the original feeling of the content inside of the div.

unless i misunderstood your question, if your just talking about cycling through 4 divs... this is defiantly possible and very easy. But if your asking if you can rotate the actual div...

Comment: Ravi, please take a minute to write your question more clearly and with more detail. Your comment here doesn't really answer Chad's question. Do you want to display each of the four DIVs in turn, or do you want to rotate the content of one DIV, or something else?

Comment: Hi Paul, 

       Here is the link http://www.avineon.com/ .open this link see on the top. four images are rotating same manner i need using javascript.