# Best way to make an image follow a circular path in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, path, jquery-animate

I have an image (red, below), that I want to make travel along a circular path. The red image should always end in the same spot as it started.

**Notes:** 
The grey circular path is invisible. I am just highlighting the path it will follow.

What is the best method/library to achieve this technique?

[image: Image, following a path]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really need a library, it's not that hard to do

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    var startAngle = 0;
    var unit = 215;

    var animate = function () {
        var rad = startAngle * (Math.PI / 180);
        $('.circle').css({
            left: 250 + Math.cos(rad) * unit + 'px',
            top: unit * (1 - Math.sin(rad)) + 'px'
        });
        startAngle--;
    }
    var timer = setInterval(animate, 10);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/TSS2G/)

Here's one  that does one loop, stops at the same place etc.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    var startAngle = 180;
    var unit = 215;

    var animate = function () {
        if (startAngle > -180) {
            var rad = startAngle * (Math.PI / 180);
            $('.circle').css({
                left: 250 + Math.cos(rad) * unit + 'px',
                top: unit * (1 - Math.sin(rad)) + 'px'
            });
            startAngle--;
            setTimeout(animate, 10);
        }
    }

    $('.circle').on('click', function() {
        startAngle = 180;
        animate();
    });

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/TSS2G/1/)

Comment: +1 but multiple clicking on the circle, makes it to run faster :p may be this is good http://jsfiddle.net/yashhy/t9Qnu/1/

Answer (score 0):

Please look into these links:

- [CSS Technique](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2013/03/03/animating-circular-paths-using-css3-transitions/#)
- Stackoverflow Answers :  [Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842789/div-moving-in-cycle-rotation-using-javascript) ||  [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551380/how-to-make-an-image-move-in-a-circular-path-using-jquery)
- JSFiddle : [Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/ankur20us/W69s6/1214/)

  ```
   var t = 0;

   function moveit() {
     t += 0.05;

     var r = 100;
     var xcenter = 100;
     var ycenter = 100;
     var newLeft = Math.floor(xcenter + (r * Math.cos(t)));
     var newTop = Math.floor(ycenter + (r * Math.sin(t)));
     $('#friends').animate({
       top: newTop,
       left: newLeft,
     }, 1, function() {
     moveit();
    });
   }

   $(document).ready(function() {
      moveit();
   });
  ```