# Jquery/javascript: circulate an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, geometry

how i can circulate an image with jquery around a circle path ? I would like something like this:

[image: example]

I have had a look at [JQuery.path](http://weepy.github.io/jquery.path/) but it doesn't work. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? Why doesn't the jquery.path code work? How did you apply your jquery.path code?

Comment: @Thew What I mean is; when i am directed to that page through the links, none of the links work. Is there an alternative link?

Comment: You could roll your own little script. It will require a little bit of maths. You could set the image position to absolute and then in js you could write a loop that sets the images css position (top,right,bottom,left) at each iteration

Comment: @user3203853 this is for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/20967994/2542763

Comment: @user3203853 no worries. Up vote the comments if they where useful. Thanks